# Simple jquery image slider with progress bar

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a simple image slider, and everything is working fine, but now sure why the progress bar, representing the active slider time, is not behaving correctly, just like the captions text.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2gayfub0/7/

Could you please have a look and point me the right direction? Thank you

## HTML

```
<div id="cycler">

    <img class="active" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=slide1">
    <span>text for slider 1</span>

    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=slide2">
    <span>text for slider 2</span>

    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=slide3">
    <span>text for slider 3</span>  

</div>


<div class="bar">

    <div class="grow">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

## JS

```
function cycleImages(){
      var $active = $('#cycler .active');
      var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler img:first');

      $('.grow').width('0px');

      $('.grow').animate( {'width': '100%'}, 2000);

      $next.css('z-index',2);

      $active.fadeOut(1000,function(){

        $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
        $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');

      });
}

$(document).ready(function(){


  var $slider = $('#cycler');
  var interval;

  function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval('cycleImages()', 2000);
  }

  function stopSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  $slider.on('mouseenter',stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);

  $('.grow').animate( {'width': '100%'}, 2000);
  startSlider();


})
```

Answer (score 0):

The page isn't redrawing between

```
    $('.grow').width('0px');
```

and

```
    $('.grow').animate( {'width': '100%'}, 2000);
```

So when the page does redraw, you just see it flicker the 0px and then the full bar.  You'll need to do a setTimeout to make it redraw after the 0px width, then start the animation.  Unfortunately that also causes asynch-ish behavior which can also be a pain.